# OpenType with Python

Tags: python, opentype

is there a python library for supporting OpenType features? where can i get it?
please do not guide to fontforge, i live in Iran , so i can not download anything from them.

Comment: You can't download via proxy in Iran?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Python Imaging Library (PIL)](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) supports OpenType.

Comment: PIL supports OpenType fonts, but it ignores OpenType features like Contextual Alternatives and Ligatures.

Answer (score 2):

If you refer OpenType Fonts, there is python library for fontforge

http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/python.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Pango](http://www.pango.org) and [Cairo](http://cairographics.org) and then its python binding 'pycairo' available in the last site too.
You can access to some (not all) OpenType features with these libraries.