# OpenType programming

Tags: .net, python, opentype

Recently i asked two questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519564/how-to-write-programs-using-advanced-opentype-features) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492508/opentype-with-python)) about using OpenType features in programs written by python and .net languages, but didn't get an answer. i realized there is no way to change text rendering engines of operating systems, or force them to use OpenType. so now want to implement my own. such a program that:

- provides a text engine that

  - receives glyph shapes from otf and ttf files and renders them in sequence of glyphs in text.
  - generates all of OTL features
- can be used in other parts of applications like controls and components of .NET or python GUI libraries.

if python and .net languages are not suitable in this situation, aware me about other programming languages or tools.
comments and answers about text rendering system of common Operating Systems, or designing text engines compatible with unicode 5.02 protocol are welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

**Pango+Cairo does what you want**

You might want to check out [Pango](http://www.pango.org/) which is a text layout and rendering engine which can handle OpenType ... see [This blog entry on advanced opentype in Pango](http://mces.blogspot.com/2007/05/advanced-opentype-features-in-pango.html).

Pango also uses [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/) for rendering fonts, blocks of text using an SVG like backend.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want do at last?

Just rendering some text but NOT with simple Windows provided API? Have a look at [this](http://marc.info/?l=cairo&m=121692252128947).

Configuring fonts OpenType features on rendering for a simple text (same script and language)? Try to implement one of this [examples](https://github.com/behdad/harfbuzz/wiki#user-examples) on C++, then bind to your favorite language. It is not a very hard task if you know a bit about C++ programming on Windows.

Doing a whole text rendering thing? Handling bidi, line wrapping and ...? Well, your answer is Pango/Cairo, but bringing them on Windows is not an easy task either, but that would be easy if you try and install [GTK#/Mono](http://mono-project.com/) on Windows.

Is not sufficient? Try to use [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) or [similar solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome) on your project.

You may find these answers useful also: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23387445/1414809) [^](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23395621/1414809)